# Why is one of my devices getting nonComplianceReason: MANAGEMENT_MODE?

Tags: android-management-api

I have a bunch of company owned devices with a few apps on them. They are all set up the same.
What is the MANAGEMENT_MODE issue and is it tied to the policyEnforcementRules?

From Google's documentation on MANAGEMENT_MODE, it means "The management mode (profile owner, device owner, etc.) doesn't support the setting."

Device listing reporting:

```
    "nonComplianceDetails": [
      {
        "nonComplianceReason": "MANAGEMENT_MODE",
        "settingName": "applications"
      }
    ],
    "ownership": "COMPANY_OWNED",
```

Relevant policy section:

```
  "policyEnforcementRules": [{
    "blockAction": {
      "blockAfterDays": 15
    },
    "wipeAction": {
      "wipeAfterDays": 30,
      "preserveFrp": True
    },
    "settingName": "applications"
  }],
```

Why am I getting this non-compliance?

EDIT: Adding screenshot from one of the phones today and the cryptic message the user's are getting (changed the blockAfterDays to 299)
[image]

EDIT2:
Adding applications section of policy. The only one that I think is odd is the Google Fi app (com.google.android.apps.tycho) which comes factory installed on some of the Pixel phones and can't be uninstalled. The phones have **data only** SIMs, some of which are from Google Fi. The app has to be disabled for these SIMs to work correctly - but on non-Pixel phones the app isn't usually installed. There unfortunately isn't a way I know of to both block install of an app and disable it when it can't be uninstalled.

```
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "OURPRIVATEPACKAGE",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
      "minimumVersionCode": APPVERSION,
    },
    {
      "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.tycho",
      "disabled": True
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.vending",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED"
    },
    {
        "packageName": "com.android.settings",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED"
    },
    {
      "packageName": "com.android.chrome",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "managed_configuration": {
        "URLBlacklist": ["*"],
        "URLWhitelist": ["WEBSITE1", "WEBSITE2", "WEBSITEN"],
        'ForceGoogleSafeSearch': True,
        'NTPContentSuggestionsEnabled': False,
      },
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },

    {
      "packageName": "com.google.enterprise.webapp.OURPRIVATEWEBAPP",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: It seems like there is something going on with the `applications` policy. Are you able to share the package id's of the applications here?

Comment: @Kevin I posted the applications section and more notes.

Comment: I actually went ahead and tried this on a Pixel device and it enrolled smoothly. Does it say which apps are non compliant?

Comment: @Kevin this only happens on a few out of the 100+ devices provisioned exactly the same. The limited non-compliance info I posted is all that is shown. Unfortunately no clearer details on what isn't setup correctly